# Google map api v3 - Event drag on marker is not trigger after a click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a form with two input text for latitude and longitude.
If I **drag and drop the marker** on Google Map API, the **values** in the input will **change**.
If I click on the map, it will change too.

However, **after this click event**, the drag and drop animation and behavior is good but my event is never trigger, so **the values do not change** at all.

I found only one thread about 'drag and click conflicts' nevertheless any solution.

So, this is my code:

```
    function launchMap(latitude, longitude, markerMap, zoom) {
        mapLaunch = true;
        var marker, map, latlng, image= '../Images/eolienne_marker_white.png', title = 'Site';
        function initMap() {
            var latlngOk = true;
            if (latitude === null || latitude === 'undefined' || latitude == 'null') {
                latlngOk = false;
            }
            if (longitude === null || longitude === 'undefined' || latitude == 'null') {
                latlngOk = false;
            }
            if (latlngOk === true) {
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    center: latlng,
                    zoom: zoom,
                    draggable: true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                if (markerMap === true) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        icon: image,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true,
                        title: title
                    });
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(center);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                if (markerMap === true) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
                markerMap = true;
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: event.latLng,
                    icon: image,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: title
                });
                map.panTo(event.latLng);
                document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (event) {
                document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**
The solution is to add the drag event to each marker creating. In my code above there is one place where I create a marker without adding the Listener. You can see below the new code working great.

```
function launchMap(latitude, longitude, markerMap, zoom) {
        mapLaunch = true;
        var marker, map, latlng, image= '../Images/eolienne_marker_white.png', title = 'Site';
        function initMap() {
            var latlngOk = true;
            if (latitude === null || latitude === 'undefined' || latitude == 'null') {
                latlngOk = false;
            }
            if (longitude === null || longitude === 'undefined' || latitude == 'null') {
                latlngOk = false;
            }
            if (latlngOk === true) {
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    center: latlng,
                    zoom: zoom,
                    draggable: true,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                });
                if (markerMap === true) {
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng,
                        icon: image,
                        map: map,
                        draggable: true,
                        title: title
                    });
                    // Call the new function for this first marker
                    googleMapsEventDrag(marker);
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(center);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                if (markerMap === true) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
                markerMap = true;
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: event.latLng,
                    icon: image,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: title
                });
                // Call the new function for this second marker
                googleMapsEventDrag(marker);
                map.panTo(event.latLng);
                document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
    }
    // New function (because calling multiple times)
    function googleMapsEventDrag(marker){
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (event) {
                document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  How does `markerMap` get set back to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding a drag event listener for the first marker you create.  But that doesn't mean the markers you're creating in response to map clicks automatically inherit that drag event listener too.  You need to add a separate event listener each time you add a marker in response to map clicks.

I think this should work:

```js
function launchMap(latitude, longitude, markerMap, zoom) {
    var marker, map, latlng, image= '../Images/eolienne_marker_white.png', title = 'Site';

    function initMap() {
        var latlngOk = true;
        if (latitude === null || latitude === 'undefined' || latitude == 'null') {
            latlngOk = false;
        }
        if (longitude === null || longitude === 'undefined' || latitude == 'null') {
            latlngOk = false;
        }
        if (latlngOk === true) {
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                center: latlng,
                zoom: zoom,
                draggable: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });
            if (markerMap === true) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    icon: image,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: title
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', markerDrag);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                map.setCenter(center);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
                if (markerMap === true) {
                    marker.setMap(null);
                }
                markerMap = true;
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: event.latLng,
                    icon: image,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: title
                });
                map.panTo(event.latLng);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', markerDrag);
            });
        }
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
}

function markerDrag(event) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
}
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. I need to add the drag event near each new marker on the map - 2 case in my code -. Use a function to call the event is the best way then to do that (you can see the good code from 'EDIT' part on my question. Thanks for the help !!